# .htaccess rewrite error when using more than one parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my .htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php
```

and this is how i work with the parameters :

```
<?php
    $request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $request = substr($request,1);
    $params = explode('/', $request);
    $safe_pages = array('page1','page2','page3');
    if(in_array($params[0],$safe_pages))
            {
                include($params[0].'.php');
            }else
            {
                include('404.php');
            }
?>
```

Let's say my site is : www.site.com

www.site.com/page -> works perfectly

www.site.com/page/parameter -> doesn't load any css or images because it looks for them in root/page instead of root/

I tried to use absolute links for my css and images but it still didn't work, so i guess the problem is in the .htaccess or i'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies not within htaccess rewrite rules, but in your html - yuor links to static content (like css, images or scripts) should start with slash to be ralative to the domain. So instead of

```
<link href="css/style.css" />
<script src="js/script.js"><script>
```

Use

```
<link href="/css/style.css" />
<script src="/js/script.js"><script>
```

Other way is to use `base` tag but it can break named anchors on your page

Comment: This is better. Can't believe i didn't think of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<base href="http://absolute_path_here/">
```

in your HTML before the closing `</head>`.

Comment: I had to use it immediateldy after <head> so it would also load the css and js and it worked. Thanks alot !